# Webpage view different between github version and local file version

Tags: web-services, user-interface, web, github

I've created a webpage on github, but the webpage is created by github is different from the local file version.

Like the following pictures:

[image: Page generated by Github]

[image: page generated by local files]

The fonts is different, and the caracter in github page is bigger than local file.

All the files are the same, I don't understand why there is such a difference and what is the solution?

Comment: We can't help you like this. You have to provide some code. If everything would be the same, it would've worked.

Comment: The Template file is on page: https://html5up.net/big-picture

Answer (score -1):

I would check your local version (using Web Develop Toolkit, Firebug, whatever), and make sure all your asset files (css, js, etc) are being loaded correctly. It looks like some css is being loaded and the only changes seem to be font, but maybe your local file isn't properly loading google fonts (or whatever you're using)

Comment: The thing is my local version interface is what I want. And the version on github is what I uploaded from my local version. So I don't know why.

Comment: Then check the github version and see if they are adding anything, that you might need to take into account.

Comment: This is not an answer. If you have enough Rep you can add comments, prevent answers like this please.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. But I've tried to download the files on github to local. And it's still different showing up between github version and local file version. What do you mean by they are adding anything?

Comment: While it may not be "the" answer, at least I provided something other than "We can't help you", in the only way that I could (since I don't have enough rep to comment everywhere yet). Why this received a downvote, I don't know. Just trying to help.